# In magento how can I show different-different list.phtml and view.phtml for different -different categories?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to show different -different **list.phtml** and **view.phtml** for different-different categories .

**My code is:**

```
<CATEGORY_4>
    <reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><name>catalog/product/list_new.phtml</name></action>
</reference>
</CATEGORY_4>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code will help you use different **list.phtml** for different categories. To use different **view.phtml** for different category products, you will have to set different attribute attribute sets and assign different templates for different attributes set. Check this link to how to do it
[Magento: template based on attribute set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735522/magento-template-based-on-attribute-set)

OR

If both the category page and product view page use the same page layout,for eg: category page and product view page uses 1column.phtml page layout, you can use different **list.phtml** and **view.phtml** for different categories by following these steps.

1. In the admin panel goto Catalog > Manage categories
2. Select the category for which you want to change the list.phtml
3. Select "*Custom Design*" tab.
4. Set "*Use parent category settings*" to No and "*Apply to products*" to Yes.
5. Add this in the "*Custom Layout Update*" section

> ```
>   <reference name="product_list">
>        <action method="setTemplate"><name>catalog/product/your-list-filename.phtml</name></action>
>   </reference>
>   <reference name="product.info">
>         <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/your-view-filename.phtml</template></action>
>   </reference>
> ```

Repeat this for all the categories that you want to change.

Comment: This one's working! Thanks James for sharing this answer. :)

Comment: Where do we put the template file: catalog/product/your-view-filename.phtml ?

Comment: @MohammedJoraid in your theme template folder eg: app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/catalog/product/your-view-filename.phtml

Comment: My bad. Didn't read the Magento version when I was browsing this question. Since I use Mag 2 the dir is Magento_Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post.
i just used this one

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/your-view-filename.phtml</template> </action>
</reference>
```

and it's working fine. but if i set one product in multiple categories so it's not handle the layout. it's call same file "your-view-filename.phtml". even i go through from both categories.

Answer (score 0):

With method:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/your-view-filename.phtml</template> </action>
</reference>
```

product layout is only applied when you visit product from the category page where you have defined it. If you visit product from homepage, for example, it's not applied. What I have done to apply layout to all products that belong to a defined category is to rewrite function getDesignSettings() from Mage_Catalog_Model_Design:

```
public function getDesignSettings($object)
{
    if ($object instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
        $customCat = 'XX';
        $productCats = $object->getAvailableInCategories();

        if (in_array($customCat, $productCats))
            $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($customCat);
        else
            $currentCategory = $object->getCategory();
    } else {
        $currentCategory = $object;
    }

    $category = null;
    if ($currentCategory) {
        $category = $currentCategory->getParentDesignCategory($currentCategory);
    }

    if ($object instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
        if ($category && $category->getCustomApplyToProducts()) {
            return $this->_mergeSettings($this->_extractSettings($category), $this->_extractSettings($object));
        } else {
            return $this->_extractSettings($object);
        }
    } else {
         return $this->_extractSettings($category);
    }
}
```